# How to find where in numpy array a zero element is preceded by at least N-1 consecutive zeros?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a numpy array (let it be a bit array for simplicity), how can I construct a new array of the same shape where 1 stands exactly at the positions where in the original array there was a zero, preceded by at least N-1 consecutive zeros?

For example, what is the best way to implement function `nzeros` having two arguments, a numpy array and the minimal required number of consecutive zeros:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
b = nzeros(a, 3)
```

Function `nzeros(a, 3)` should return

```
array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
```

Comment: If either of the answers worked, consider accepting one?

Answer (score 10):

**Approach #1**

We can use [`1D` convolution](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.convolve.html) -

```
def nzeros(a, n):
    # Define kernel for 1D convolution
    k = np.ones(n,dtype=int)

    # Get sliding summations for zero matches with that kernel
    s = np.convolve(a==0,k)

    # Look for summations that are equal to n value, which will occur for
    # n consecutive 0s. Remember that we are using a "full" version of
    # convolution, so there's one-off offsetting because of the way kernel
    # slides across input data. Also, we need to create 1s at places where
    # n consective 0s end, so we would need to slice out ending elements.
    # Thus, we would end up with the following after int dtype conversion
    return (s==n).astype(int)[:-n+1]
```

Sample run -

```
In [46]: a
Out[46]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])

In [47]: nzeros(a,3)
Out[47]: array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])

In [48]: nzeros(a,2)
Out[48]: array([0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
```

**Approach #2**

Another way to solve and this could be considered as a variant of the `1D` convolution approach, would be to use `erosion`, because if you look at the outputs, we can simply erode the mask of `0s` from the starts until `n-1` places. So, we can use [`scipy.ndimage.morphology's` `binary_erosion`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.binary_erosion.html) that also allow us to specify the portion of kernel center with its `origin` arg, hence we will avoid any slicing. The implementation would look something like this -

```
from scipy.ndimage.morphology import binary_erosion

out = binary_erosion(a==0,np.ones(n),origin=(n-1)//2).astype(int)
```

Comment: Beautiful solution and will be way more efficient than a for loop.

For OPs sake would you mind explaining what the convolution does, why we're creating a vector of ones, etc?

Comment: @Lagerbaer Added some comments.

Comment: That's sheer beauty...

Answer (score 1):

Using for loop:

```
def nzeros(a, n):
  #Create a numpy array of zeros of length equal to n
  b = np.zeros(n)

  #Create a numpy array of zeros of same length as array a
  c = np.zeros(len(a), dtype=int)

  for i in range(0,len(a) - n):
    if (b == a[i : i+n]).all():  #Check if array b is equal to slice in a
      c[i+n-1] = 1

  return c
```

Sample Output:

```
print(nzeros(a, 3))
[0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0]
```